# Allow admin roles to add images to comment replies

Tags: images, comments, user-roles

this may be a step too far but I publish occasional tutorials on my personal blog and sometimes in comments get asked questions where an image would be very helpful to include as the answer. I've done a plug-in search and also looked for code but come up with nothing. Is there any way I can allow those with Admin role to upload an image as part of their reply to a comment? I don't want to allow readers to upload images really. Also I'm not really looking to add a link to an image in the reply, I'd ideally like it in the comment reply itself. Just a 'too difficult' or 'can't be done' response would put me out of my misery :-)

Comment: Did you come across this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-images/ You could just edit the code and set the currect_user to an admin capability for the upload.

Comment: Hi Christine, thank you I saw that plugin but didn't think about editing it I must admit. I think you could have the solution though. I'm not sure what files it includes but would it just be a case of surrounding some code somewhere with: `<?php if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' )) { ...code from plug-in here... } ?>` and this code would prevent the option to upload an image on my comments form from appearing unless a site admin were logged in?

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a very simple process, please check the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and quickest way that you can do this is by downloading the [Comment Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-images/) plugin and limit access to the upload feature by the function [current_user_can](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can). As the WP page demonstrates, use:

```
if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
 // Plugin code here
}
```

I had a **very** quick look at the plugin code and you may need to add this function to the `add_image_upload_form` function. All and all, this should only take you a few minutes to setup.

Comment: Hi Christine, I accepted the answer. I've added the plug-in and it does as expected. Haven't yet tried to edit the code and add the restriction as I have to race out but from your response that seems to make perfect sense to me. I'll have a play later.

Comment: Good luck and let us know if it doesn't work out and we will assist.

Comment: Hi Christine, I added the edit to plugin.php at line 169 `if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {` and then to close it at line 182 `}` and as far as I can see it works as expected. The image I already added by way of reply shows to all but the option to upload images only shows to me. I have tested new comments both logged in (as admin) and logged out (posting as guest) to test and all appears fine to me.

Comment: Glad to hear it Paul and good luck with your site.